# web development terms and dictionary

Tags: web, definition

I m looking for a resource where i can find terms, definitions and explanation related to web development in general.

For example : 
definition and explanation of shtml. etc.

do you know any references ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go here : http://www.javvin.com/softwareglossary/

Answer (score 0):

w3schools is a pretty good starting point. Complete with interactive examples

Comment: not really..I M not looking for a basic tutorials, i just want definitions and terms. but thanks.